# How to log any inserts or updates in the database using Spring AOP annotations?

Tags: spring-aop, pointcuts

My application has a DAO layer which has methods like

```
    @Override
public void save(final Role role) {
    // save in database }
```

Now eevry time such save or update method is called I need to run an AOP aspect and log this in database.

I do not want my aspwect to run on methods which run only select queries.

What will be my AOP pointcut for like run when any methods which is save or upadate in dao packages?

Please help